How to add copy button in ngx-markdown tag in angular
I want to add copy button when in response have code like below.

please see my uploaded image what i want.
<markdown  class="variable-binding" [data]="markdown"></markdown>

  markdown = `## Markdown __rulez__!
---

### Syntax highlight
\`\`\`typescript
const language = 'typescript';
\`\`\`

### Lists
1. Ordered list
2. Another bullet point
   - Unordered list
   - Another unordered bullet

### Blockquote
> Blockquote to the max`;
}


I am using this code. I want to when in response have code like image then show copy button to copy only provided code like chatGBT copy button.
Click here for stack Bizz code

Copy to clipboard functionality is given by ngx-markdown. You have to configure it.
Step: 1. To add Clipboard library to your package.json use the following command.
npm install clipboard@^2.0.11 --save

Step: 2. To activate Clipboard allowing copy-to-clipboard you will need to include in angular.json example below...
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/clipboard/dist/clipboard.min.js",
]

Step: 3. Clipboard plugin
<markdown clipboard class="variable-binding" [data]="markdown"></markdown>

Reference: ngx-markdown

